# Angular 2- Error: Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'AbstractControl'

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am using the angular rc4 release to write an application where I have to impose few validation rules to form components like `required`, `minlength` along with some custom validator `emailValidator`.

When I pass one built in and one custom validator to the `Validators.compose` function, IDEs (both Webstorm & VS Code) display me compile time error messages like the one shown below:

[image]

However, you can see that in the above screenshot if both validators are built in, there is no error message.

The definition of my custom validator is given below:

```
static emailValidator(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} {
    if (control.value.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return {'invalidEmailAddress': true };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing the type of `control` parameter from `AbstractControl` to `Control` as shown below:

```
static emailValidator(control: Control): {[key: string]: boolean} {
    if (control.value.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return {'invalidEmailAddress': true };
    }
}
```

`Control` class extends from `AbstractControl`. I still don't understand why I get this error message when I use `FormControl` or `AbstractControl`.

Comment: I had previously have FormControl and replaced with AbstractControl and it work. Thanks for the example !

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my case, I was calling a custom EmailValidator class included from a shared Angular 7 library I created. Because of

```
"@angular/forms": "~7.2.2"
```

in my `package.json` file two different minor versions of `@angular/forms` got installed for my library and the application including it, resulting in different TypeScript definition files. The solution was to

1. Delete node_modules folder for both projects
2. Delete package-lock.json for both projects
3. Do a npm install for both projects
4. Reinstall the library

Answer (score 0):

This is rather strange, have you already tried with the `FormControl`?

Like this?

```
static emailValidator(control : FormControl){
    // RFC 2822 compliant regex
    let EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i;

    return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(control.value) ? null : {
      invalidEmailAddress:true
    }
}
```

I do use `Validator.compose` in my components and it works just fine.

Comment: Yes, I did. In fact first I was using `FormControl` which is inherited from `AbstractControl`.

Comment: @AJQarshi exactly, that's why this error is weird, I usually declare the FormControl first
`
    this.emailControl = new FormControl('',Validators.compose([Validator.required,ValidatorService.emailValidator]),ValidatorService.checkEmai(this._httpService));
`
then I assign it to a key of the FormGroup input object